# Add multiple lists to global-abbrev-table

Tags: abbrev

How can I add multiple lists to `global-abbrev-table`?

```
(defconst tablet1 
   '( ("all" "l")     ("as" "as")      ("can" "k")
      ("some" "so")   ("than" "n")     ("that" "ta")
      ("there" "tr")  ("this" "th")    ("time" "ti") ))

(defconst tablet2
   '( ("again" "ag")  ("any" "n")    ("before" "bf")
      ("every" "ev")  ("from" "fm")  ("good" "g")
      ("here" "he")   ("long" "lg")  ("not" "n")
      ("such" "sc")   ("the" "t")    ("would" "d") ))


(defun abbrev ()
  (kill-all-abbrevs)
  (define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table tablet1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```el
(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table (append tablet1 tablet2))
```

The point is that the second argument of `define-abbrev-table` must be a single list (of two-element lists). `append` lets you combine two or more such lists into one by concatenating all the argument lists into one list [1].

See the doc string of `append` with `C-h f append`:

```
append is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(append &rest SEQUENCES)

Concatenate all the arguments and make the result a list.
The result is a list whose elements are the elements of all the arguments.
Each argument may be a list, vector or string.
The last argument is not copied, just used as the tail of the new list.
```

BTW, it is now tested and it works fine.

---

[1] `append` actually makes copies of all its argument lists except the last. This is irrelevant for the above discussion, but it is important in general. The last argument is "shared" structure: you can get to it through the `tablet2` variable and also through the result of `append`. See the Emacs Lisp manual, section "Building Cons Cells and Lists" for some discussion. You can get to that section with `C-h i g (elisp) RET i cons cells RET`.

Comment: How can I handle the last argument?

Comment: Have tried it and `would` still gets changed even if it occurs as the last argument.

Comment: Sorry, what? Why shouldn't it? If you are talking about the "last argument is not copied" note in the doc string of `append`, that refers to `tablet2`: the last argument of `append`: it's a somewhat technical point having to do with shared structure - see the Emacs Lisp manual, section "Building Cons Cells and Lists".

Comment: Would I need to add another entry to `tablet2`?

Comment: Why would you? As I said, it works fine: did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did.  Why is the documentation bothering the user with the last argument not being copied?

Comment: Because it may be important in some circumstances.

Comment: But not in my case, it seems.

Comment: Not in many cases, but the documentation has to be as complete as possible.